# How to align multiple divs in another?

Tags: css, html, alignment

So here's my HTML:

```
...
<div class="header">
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="center">
<img class="logo" src="linktomyimage.com/image.png" />
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
</div>

<!-- And the desired result is: -->
[ [LEFT] [CENTER] [RIGHT] ]
```

The only CSS I have is:

```
* {
margin: 0px;
}
img.logo {
display: block;   margin-left: auto;   margin-right: auto; 
}
```

I really need help to align the three divs on the whole page. Also div.center must have the same size as the image, aka width - 800px and height - 600px.

Comment: show your css code for the classes left, center and right

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks much more like a table than divisions to me...

```
<table class="header"><tr>
    <td class="left"></td>
    <td class="center">
        <img class="logo" src="linktomyimage.com/image.png" />
    </td>
    <td class="right"></td>
</tr></table>
```

Think about so CSS afterwards :

```
table.header{
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table.header td{
    vertical-align: top;
    border: 1px solid #404040;
}

table.header td.center{
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
```

This is just a code sample, get the idea, and adapt to your own needs ^^

Comment: Your code worked but please look at this:
http://www.gameplay-universe.uphero.com/test.html
There are white spaces between the tables. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add borders to the cells, same color as your grey frame : #404040. This will "fill the blanks". Answer edited.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Look in the webpage again. Any other way?

Comment: A dirty way would be to add `padding: -1px;` to `table.header td`.

Answer (score 1):

Add these classes to your css

```
.left
{
 display:inline-block;
 width:25%;
}
.center
{
 display:inline-block;
 width:50%;
}
.right
{
 display:inline-block;
 width:25%;
}
```

Comment: add this class
.center img{width:100%;}

Answer (score 0):

With the following markup, 2 solutions come to mind:

### MARKUP

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="left">
        Some left test
    </div>
    <div class="center">
    <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" />
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        Some right text
    </div>
</div>
```

### Solution #1

Float left and right sides and use display-block on the center

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/NeCKf/3/)**

### Css

```
.header
{
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}
.left
{
    float:left
}
.right
{
    float:right;
}
.center
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

---

### Solution #2

Use `text-align: justify;` on the header element.

Then stretch the content to take up 100% width

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/NeCKf/1/)**

### CSS

```
.header
{
    text-align: justify;
    width:100%;
}
.header > div
{
    display: inline-block;
}
.header:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.left, .centre, .right {
float:left;
}
```

What float:left does is, is it'll make each container organize itself from the left, so you get:

[LEFT]-[CENTRE]-[RIGHT]