# 3 divs in a row , 1 in middle but have a float left inside the div

Tags: html, css

Have a question about a Website im building.
The Header part of the website contain inside it 3 divs that should be in the same row.
1 in the left side , 1 in the middle of the screen , and 1 in the right side.
The Header width is 100%.

```
#header {
background-color:#352618;
height: 100px;
width:100%;
}
```

and the three divs inside:

```
#logo
{
float:left;
width:200px;
height:80px;
margin-top:6px;
margin-left:20px;
}

#Menu {
font-size:17px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding-top:20px;
width:100%; /** before it was 850 px **/
}

#LanguageSelect
{
float:right;
width:120px;
height:80px;
font-size:14px;
padding-top:60px;
padding-right:10px;
}
```

Ok , now the question is :
The menu part is the menu of the header , it's a `<li>` and `<ul>` drop down menu.
Code:

```
   <div id="Menu" class="text_blue">
    <ul id="menu_noya">
        <li class="head_item">
            <a href="mine.html?search_engines">Women</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://google.com/">Google</a>                         </li>
                    <li><a href="http://yahoo.com/">Yahoo</a>       </li>
                    <li><a href="http://live.com/">Live        Search</a></li>
                </ul>
        </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
```

And the result is that the Logo is placed OK, the LanguageSelect is OK , but the menu sticks to the left and not in the **middle of the screen**, why? because in order the make the `<li>` and `<ul>` in the same row , I needed to use a `float:left` so the menu can be in same row.

What can I do in order it to be in the middle , without using `float:left`?

- another question : I'm using this font: Hiragino Mincho Pro , and when the font is < 18px; it doesn't lood good , like it doesn't have anti-alisting.

***Here's an example of how it looks in general.***
http://jsfiddle.net/GEKkf/

Thanks alot for help and read!
Elroy.

Comment: Try to put the code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) which is much easier for others to have a look.

Comment: use 'clear:both', if you want to cancel the float which is left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following classes:

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/GEKkf/1/)**

```css
#header {
    text-align: center;
}

#Menu {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Also, for another way doing this, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17643178/703717).

Comment: Thanks alot ! Works ! appricate it , Thanks to anybody else who helped, the     display:inline-block; fixed it .

Answer (score 0):

Put all three divs in `float: left;` and put them as 33% width (or a tiny amount lower than 33% if you want to)

Then add an html element which has `clear:both;` after to make sure you push the rest of the page down.  You can also use the css `:after` if you prefer.

Comment: Doesn't work , every each element goes to other part of the page.

Comment: What do you mean it goes to the other part of the page?  You can try float: right; if you mean they are in the wrong order.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GEKkf/
As you can see , the menu sticks to the logo , it should be in middle of the screen ,that's the problem. Thanks , Elroy.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GEKkf/2/   don't view it in the fiddle though.  the menu gets pushed down below.  View on a normal screen.

Comment: Iv'e tryed the 33% and all goes float:left ,its a big prolem since they don't go all equal or lower then 33, I prefer fixing it on my coding because menu isn't >33 its bigger

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the li.head_item:hover ul entry in your CSS file to the following:

```
li.head_item:hover ul { 
position: absolute;
 display: block; 
 width: 142px;
 background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
```